# jQuery & CSS - match a div's height while animating

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, slidedown

I have two `<div>`'s floated left within a parent `<div>`. Using jQuery, the `div.will_slide_down` will slide down at some point (using `$("div.will_slide_down").slideDown()`). When it is sliding down, the `div.first`'s height should also increase to match the height of the `div.second` at the same time.

How can I do that?

```
 <div class="wrap">
      <div class="first" style="width: 200px; float: left;"></div>
      <div class="second" style="width: 700px; float: left;">
           <p>BlaBlaBla</p>
           <div class="will_slide_down" style="display: none">Some hidden text</div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

The only way I can think of is to run a function when the `slideDown` of the `div.second` is complete, but this will mess up the layout. It should happen at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate) and the step function. The step function is fired at each 'step' of the animation. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('div.will_slide_down').animate({height: 'show'}, {step: function(now, fx){
    var new_height = $('div.second').height;
    $('div.first').css('height', new_height);
}});
```

Comment: +1 for the `step` function; I never realised that existed beforehand. Thanks! =)

Comment: Yeah wicked, not seen the step in any of the books I learned from. Unless I forgot it, maybe it's new, says in docs second version of animate

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your slide down will be triggered by some event, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("element").click(function() {
    follower($("div.first"));
$("div.will_slide_down").slideDown()).
})
    })

    function follower(el) {
        if ($("div.will_slide_down").is(":animated"))
        {
            var leader = $("div.will_slide_down");
            while(leader.is(":animated"))
                  {
                  el.animate({
                      height: leader.css('height')
                  },3000);
                  }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, is position `.will_slide_down` somewhere off-screen - without hiding it - at page-load to measure its height. Then you can hide it, move it back and use the height (adding the initial height of `.second`...) to calculate the new height of `.first` and just animate the two at the same moment.